# Why Isn't my for loop for my leap year program working?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

Our assignment is to make a for loop program and while loop program out of our switch statement program, so I just need to know why my for loop program isn't running and if you want to check my while too, that would be great.

while loop:

```
/* 
* File:   main.cpp
* Author: Jorge Elias
*
* Created on October 22, 2017, 11:53 PM
*/

#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
 int main( ) {
     //Assigning the Integers
     int month,days,year;
     //Asking User for inputs
     cout<<"Please enter the Year: ";cin>>year;
     cout<<"Please enter the month (1-12): ";cin>>month;
     //Switch statement to determine how many days there are in a month
     switch(month) {
         case 1:
         case 3:
         case 4:
         case 5:
         case 6:
         case 7:
         case 8:
         case 10:
         case 12:
            cout<<"31 days"<<endl;
            break;            
    case 9:
    case 11:
        cout<<"30 days"<<endl;
        break;
 while(month<0){
        cout<<"INVALID INPUT! Please enter month number between 1-12"<<endl;
        break;
        }

//Determine if the Year inputed by the User is a Leap Year or not
       case 2:

       while(year>0){
       if(year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)
       {
           cout<<"This is a leap year, 29 days"<<endl;
       }
           else if( year % 100 !=0 && year % 4 == 0) 
           {
               cout<<"This is a leap year, 29 days"<<endl;
           }
           else
               cout<<"there are 28 days";
       break;
}
}           
return 0;
 }
```

for loop:
          * 
     * File:   main.cpp
     * Author: Jorge Elias
     *
     * Created on October 22, 2017, 11:53 PM
     */

```
 #include<cstdlib>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 #include<iomanip>
 using namespace std;

 /*
  * 
  */
int main( ) {
    //Assigning the Integers
    int month,days,year;
    //Asking User for inputs
    cout<<"Please enter the Year: ";cin>>year;
    cout<<"Please enter the month (1-12): ";cin>>month;
    //Switch statement to determine how many days there are in a month
    for(month>1; month<12;){
        switch(month) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            cout<<"31 days"<<endl;
        break;
        case 9:
        case 11:
            cout<<"30 days"<<endl;
        break;
        for(month<1;month>12;){
            cout<<"INVALID INPUT! Please enter month number between 1-12"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        //Determine if the Year inputed by the User is a Leap Year or not
        case 2:
        for(year % 100 == 0;year % 400 == 0;)
        {
            cout<<"This is a leap year, 29 days"<<endl;
            for( year % 100 !=0; year % 4 == 0;) 
            {
               cout<<"This is a leap year, 29 days"<<endl;
            }
            for(year >0;)
            {
                cout<<"there are 28 days";
                break;
          }
       }
    }     
    }
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Please describe the current failing behavior.

Comment: its giving me an error message saying that i need a primary expression before the parenthesis

Comment: and on what line is that error

Comment: What are the loops for?

Comment: It seems that you have misunderstood how `for` loops (and loops in general) have to be written. Please look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while

Answer (score 2):

These are your for-loops:

```
for(month>1; month<12;)
for(year % 100 == 0;year % 400 == 0;)
for(year >0;)
```

## None of those look like normal for-loops.

---

A normal for-loop has 3 separate parts:

```
for([init]; [test]; [mod]) { [body] }
```

Those 3 parts are:

- `[init]` is an Initialization expression, such as `i = 0`
- `[test]` is a predicate to decide if the loop continues, such as `i < 11`
- `[mod]` is a modifying expression to update the loop each time, such as `++i`

Your for-loops only have 1 or 2 parts, and they are not *initializer / predicate / modifier*.

***Example***

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { printf("Count is %d\n", i); }
```

Resulting in

```
Count is 0
Count is 1
Count is 2
Count is 3
Count is 4
[...]
Count is 9
```

Comment: Sadly, the first two loops are "valid" enough to compile. Maybe it's worth to mention that statements like `for (;;) {/* infinite loop */}` are valid. And used (with precautions).